# How to give windows priority over applications?

Tags: windows

For example, when I run two instances of PiFast, I can barely move my mouse, because that program is using all the CPU resources, but I would like to know if it's possible to give windows priority over other programs, so I can still at least close the current program if the whole system is irresponsible?

Comment: Also, I would like to add that I don't want to make it work on only specific programs, because it's not always the same. (For example, when using Chrome, or Firefox, or any resource intensive program), if it ends up using too many resources, the mouse will almost freeze and I can't close the program that's causing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `start` from the command line. It has options for launching a process at a specific priority, in this case you probably want to do `start /BELOWNORMAL pifast.exe`.

Comment: +1: Great answer.  Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than increasing windows priority, you can turn down the process's priority with taskmanager - I believe if its set to low it will only use 'spare' processor power. 'Windows' is a fair number of processes (as is any OS), and you'd have to work out and increase the priority of each to do what you want to do.

Comment: The trouble is, how do you get to the Task Manager if windows is being unresponsive (aside from pressing Ctrl+Shift+Esc and waiting until Windows gets around to it?)

Comment: give task manager higher priority, and start it before the cr** hits the fan?